# Archimedes' principle on Scalars fields

Tags: field-theory, tensor-calculus

**Archimedes' principle on a Scalar field**

First of all, it's my first question here on Stack exchange, and I am very glad to have found this website. Somehow, it's warm me a bit inside to see how much people care about the beautiful think that is Physics.
Im a sorry cause for the moment, I am just a pasionnate of physique, and i am not a student.Also, I am sorry for my poor english, french is my first language.

My questions are regarding sclar field.

1. Is there something like the archimedes principle for a scalar field. So if I move a quantity of energies from a scalar field, as consequence would the energie will press back where the region of the scalar field moved?
2. If yes, what would be the mathematical instrument to define it ?
3. Do we have an example of tensor being incompatible with scalar fields ?

Again, thank you and if I wasn't clear enough, don't hesitate to ask for some clarification.

Comment: *if I move a quantity of energies from a scalar field* It isn’t clear what this means, or how you could do it.

Comment: *tensor energies* It isn’t clear what this means. Are you talking about the energy-momentum-stress tensor? If so, a scalar field has one.

Comment: There are thousands of scalar fields relevant to physics, which all behave differently and require different intuition. There's no one behavior of a scalar field in general. This is like asking if there's, say, a universal law that determines the behavior of all _plants_.

Comment: @G.Smith

I don't know either,how we could move a quantity of energies from a scalar field. I am thinking maybe if it was possible with a maximum langragien density overshoot. Polarisation of scalar a field, or I don't know , something like a Pauli exclusion principle for a type of energie on a particular scalar. Maybe I am mixing things,.
 Yes,Energy-momentum-stress tensor was definitely something i had in mind. So you imply that scalars fields  have tensor? Or they have something like a Archimedes principal.( would give a gradient)

Comment: @knzhou
Thanks you for the personal analogy, that I think, you design from my picture. If you really want to know, I was referring to the Higgs field. I am thinking, maybe that the mechanisme of Higgs is not about coupling at all , but it's about polarisation of this scalar.

Comment: In mainstream physics, scalar fields do not and cannot have polarization. What would it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The buoyancy from the Archimedes principle results from the gradient of pressure on the liquid. Maybe you are thinking about effects resulting from gradient of scalar fields.

Another example is heat flow, that results from the gradient of temperature in a wall. Or classical gravity acceleration, that comes from the gradient of gravity potential.

In order to describe the stress state in a solid, it is necessary a stress tensor for each point. The pressure scalar field used for liquids is not possible here, due to the capacity of solids of supporting shear stresses.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a confusion here. Archimedes principle is about classical fields, not quantum mechanical, where the term scalar has a particular meaning.

Fields in general QFT  have a [vacuum expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_expectation_value)  of zero, so there is no energy to move or not move. Fields are all over (x,y,z,t) and give measurable results only when creation and annihilation operators operate on them. They are a coordinate system.

In the comments you mention the scalar field of Higgs. That is the exception in the standard model , and has a vacuum expectation value of 246.22 GeV . BUT that does not mean  it is similar to what energy in a classical field would mean. It is a value that appeared during electroweak symmetry breaking in the [Big Bang current cosmological model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html), in one epoch, and is not available at our time to be treated like a classical fluid. It is there because the masses of the W and Z were measured to be what they are.

So the answer in general is that fields in quantum field theory are  not the same as fields in classical theories where Archimedes principles work.

Comment: I think you may be unfamiliar with much of classical field theory. Scalar fields can be classical, and the Higgs field owes its nonzero VEV to its Mexican hat potential, not any specifically quantum effect.

Comment: J.G. you are correct, classical fields can have any vector or scalar formulation. I suppose it is the Higgs that makes t a QFT question. The hat is a simplified way of looking at the potential.It is QFT that is at work with the real calculations.

Comment: @annav
I really do have diffuclty to understand the true meaning of SSB appearing with time and temperature. Let's say that higgs field appear at 10e20 K cause we have a SSB. It's create a field with the potentiel of our mexican hat. Do it mean, that if in a space (x,y,z) we augmente the temperature at 10e20 K, we lose our potential?  Or again, SSB are not mean to be revearse?